# ASP.Net Cache busting approach not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, caching, iis

I am trying to solve the problem of browser caching. Whenever there are any changes in any of the js and css files, the files are served from the browser cache rather than from server, I researched on internet and found [this great post](http://madskristensen.net/post/cache-busting-in-aspnet) from mads krinstinsen.

I included the following class and method in a class in my `App_Code` folder.

```
using System; 
using System.IO; 
using System.Web; 
using System.Web.Caching; 
using System.Web.Hosting;

public class Fingerprint 
{ 
  public static string Tag(string rootRelativePath) 
  { 
    if (HttpRuntime.Cache[rootRelativePath] == null) 
    { 
      string absolute = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~" + rootRelativePath);

      DateTime date = File.GetLastWriteTime(absolute); 
      int index = rootRelativePath.LastIndexOf('/');

      string result = rootRelativePath.Insert(index, "/v-" + date.Ticks); 
      HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(rootRelativePath, result, new CacheDependency(absolute)); 
    }

      return HttpRuntime.Cache[rootRelativePath] as string; 
  } 
}
```

Later i changed the references in all my aspx pages(almost 500 locations) like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=Fingerprint.Tag("/Scripts/JQuery/jquery.color.js")%>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=Fingerprint.Tag("/Scripts/JQuery/jquery.glowbuttons.js?v=1.1")%>"></script>
```

As suggested i have also added the following rewrite rules and installed rewrite module in IIS.

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="fingerprint">
          <match url="([\S]+)(/v-[0-9]+/)([\S]+)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/{R:3}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

**Now the problem i am facing**

This all worked a charm in my development environment. When i  published the code to the iis (uat and my local iis) the same code did not work.

The `Fingerprint.Tag()` method returns wrong URLs.

**My development URL goes like below**

```
http://localhost:54992/login.aspx
```

**My IIS website URL goes like below**

```
http://www.example.com/myClientName/login.aspx
```

You might have noticed an extra level of url segment `(\myClientName\)`on IIS, this is what causing the problem.

I have also added the logic to add the `myClientName` part in URL unfortunately that also did not work.

On IIS hosted website i gent plenty of 404 errors because the url path skips the *myClientName* part.

**UPDATE 1**

I also tried it with the following another version of same method, which checks if the code is running in iisexpress or on Full IIS and generate the paths accordingly

```
 public static string Tag(string rootRelativePath)
    {

        if (rootRelativePath.Contains("~"))
            rootRelativePath = rootRelativePath.Replace("~", string.Empty);

        bool isRunningInIisExpress = Process.GetCurrentProcess()
                                .ProcessName.ToLower().Contains("iisexpress");

        if (HttpRuntime.Cache[rootRelativePath] == null)
        {
            string siteAlias = string.Empty;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteName"]))
                siteAlias = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteName"].ToString();
            string absolute = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~" + rootRelativePath);

            DateTime date = File.GetLastWriteTime(absolute);
            int index = rootRelativePath.LastIndexOf('/');

            string result = rootRelativePath.Insert(index, "/v-" + date.Ticks);
            if (!isRunningInIisExpress)
            {
                siteAlias = "/" + siteAlias;
                result = siteAlias + result;
            }
            if (File.Exists(absolute))
                HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(rootRelativePath, result, new CacheDependency(absolute));
        }

        return HttpRuntime.Cache[rootRelativePath] as string;
    }
```

Please guide me to right direction.

Comment: what happens if you turn out the rewrite rule? will be de path on dev on live the same?

Comment: @Dexion do you mean like <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:3}/{R:1}" />

Comment: yes. i suggest to compare the iis/site configs also.

Comment: This rewrite rule is introduced first time in config.both, the development config file and iis config file have the same rewrite rule, should they be modified? i don't know much about rewrite rule conventions

Comment: delete the rules on dev and live and check the urls - you need to determine that the rules or something other adds the extra folder level.

Comment: The extra level is nothing but the site Alias in IIS, it is not folder, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116538/discussion-between-devjosh-and-dexion).

Comment: remove the alias and/or use the default web site on the live env.

Comment: i can not do this because we have many websites running under default websites.

Comment: this is the problem. solution: use relative path for the scripts or set the site for another port instead of 80 and you can run it as it is in the dev.  i write it as an answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Use relative path or set the site a different port, so it will run in live env on the same way as in the dev env.

Comment: Making the changes in references is a tedious job as there may be say 90/100 pages and each page has css and js references in it.
i am not permitted to run the website on a different port. Thanks